# QT/pyqt tag/token input

Tags: python, qt, qt5, pyqt5

Is it possible to create tag/token input in QT5/pyqt5 ?

I am creating gui app where user can store image/photo and add tags. Specific tags are already in a database, user should be able to choose from existing ones (or create new ones if needed).
Lets say:
Image 1 Tags:
(Clouds),(Tree),(mountain),road

User has chosen first 2 tags from database and added "road" which was not in database.

Currently I can create and populate QComboBox with database data which would just append to QLineEdit, later on i can process it back by formatting text. But it would be way more convenient to have something like tag/token input (*exactly* like in attached image):

- Single line input
- Each tag/text has its own 'remove' button
- visually easy to distinguish between existing tags and tags just added (text vs box with close button)

Does QT has something like that out of the box, or should i create graphical icon for each text in custom widget?

[image]

Comment: Do you want a system similar to the one that has SO to add tags? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: @eyllanesc, I don't think I am familiar with it, could you point me to example or where i could read about it ? thanks!

Comment: mmm, I did not understand you, explain yourself better, what I point out is that the functionality you want is similar to the one that StackOverflow uses to add the tags that are at the bottom of your question.

Comment: @eyllanesc, oh! You mean like on StackOverflow! :) yes, similar to that one, or just like one in attached image. Do you know how to implement it in QT/pyqt ? So far I haven't tried anything as I couldn't find anything online about tokens in QT. My current 'solution' is the one i described in question - populating QComboBox and with its selection appending QLineEdit (as a simple text)

Comment: I am thinking about possibilities but an image is not very clear, you should indicate a list of requirements, that is: *I want A but not B, I want C and also D*. An image can be interpreted in many ways.

Comment: I have marked an answer as duplicate, try it and improve it

Comment: @eyllanesc I just did, That duplicate answer is nowhere near my qustion and attached image i am afraid :( but thanks for suggesion, that helps as well!

Comment: but I think it's a good starting point, I do not see that you've shown that you've tried, and unfortunately I'm thinking that we'll do your job, the previous answer implements the property of having multiple tags based on a model, you have to add it couple of features and it will be what you want, at least try something and I will see if it is necessary to reopen the question.

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/nicktrandafil/tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I have a naive implementation of such widget [here](https://github.com/nicktrandafil/tags). It is not finished yet, but the key functionality is implemented.

So, the implementation is based on `QTextLayout` class. Сompleted tokens are kept as an class member and are painted in `paintEvent` method. Сurrently editing token is painted with `QTextLayout` object. A cursor is painted with `QTextLayout` object too. User key presses are handled in `keyPressEvent` (typing, navigation). The widget also has a completer. This is the core idea, for more details, observe the code.

There is much work to do: customizable looking, tokenizing policies, removing by click on cross, etc. But it could be used for your own purposes or as an starting point for your own widget.

The implementation of `QLineEdit` was very helpful for me.